# DateTime::createFromFormat stopped functioning

Tags: php

I used to use this code to display an auto on sale date and time for tickets on my web page but a few months ago it just stopped working and breaks my entire page. I have a date that I pick which is the "onsale". If today's date is before this, it should display the below. Any thoughts?

```
        <?php       

            $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('onsale'));
                echo $date->format('D, M d');
                echo get_field('onsale_time');

            } 
            else { echo get_field( 'price' );
            }
        ?>
```

If I delete

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('onsale'));
echo $date->format('D, M d');
```

It won't break. I am using PHP 5.4.24

Here is the entire section

```
<?php   $onsale_date = strtotime(get_field('onsale'));
            $now = time();

    if ($onsale_date) { ?>

    <div class="event-ticket-link">

        <div class="cost"> 


        <?php
            if ($onsale_date > $now) {
        ?>  

        On Sale

        <?php       

            $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('onsale'));
                echo $date->format('D, M d');
                echo get_field('onsale_time');

            } 
            else { echo get_field( 'price' );
            }
        ?>

        </div>

        <h4 class="buy-tickets"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#tickets">Get Tickets</a></h4>

        </div>

        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `get_field('onsale')`?

Comment: Things don't just 'stop working', and in the case of PHP if there's a problem with the function there will be an error or warning in your server error log. Post any errors in the server log, and look hard at whatever you changed when this 'stopped working'

Comment: It's a JQuery Date Picker displaying yymmdd format. This particular one is 141121

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons that code could have stopped working:

- the input has changed. In your case, get_field('onsale') could have changed. It should have the "Ymd" format : check that get_field('onsale') looks like YYYYmmdd, e.g. 20141108 for today's date
- configuration changes: maybe you updated PHP and it now requires you to set a locale before using DateTime family functions, maybe the server locale changed, ... (things like this can happen, particularly with date functions: they are sensitive to configuration).

Comment: I'm using Wordpress as my CMS and a Custom Fields plugin. The date picker used for the "onsale" field is part of this. When I upgraded the plugin, this stopped working. The other custom fields still show up just fine, but the DateTime formatting stopped.